# remove <a href> from a draggable when being dragged - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this site which is a grid of draggable links. When dragged a drop down  appears where the user can drag to trash the draggable.

Problem is that when they drop it on the droppble, the link opens up! Which is not supposed to be happening. I've tried adding

```
ui.draggable.find('a').removeAttr('href')
```

to my handleDropEvent function, but it didn't help.

Any javascript geniuses care to take a look?

**EDIT** I tried also adding :

```
ui.draggable.find('a').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
```

to the following like so:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({ start: function( event, ui ) {$('#dropdownAddTile').slideDown();ui.draggable.find('a').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });},  stop: function() {$('#dropdownAddTile').slideUp();}, containment: '#container', snap:'.droppable', snapMode:'inner', revert:'invalid',snapTolerance: 32});
```

**ANOTHER EDIT**

I should point out (just figured out) that I have the draggable class applied to an href like this :

```
<a href class="draggable">
```

So solutions so far have caused the problem where we remove the link and it stops the draggable from being draggable! Is there another way?

Comment: It is working for me (Chrome). BTW, you have a PHP variable not defined : check console (F12)

Comment: It's working in Firefox 18 and 19.

Comment: @NessDan It's not working for me in FF 19, are you dragging the amazon item to the trash? or just moving it between grids? the bug is in the former.

Comment: It sometimes (mostly) happens with random links on FF.

Comment: @Nelson You're right, the trash opens up the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they are dragged set a click handler to prevent the default action, like so:

```
ui.draggable.find('a').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

As I said, do it when they are dragged in case it's too late when doing it in the dropped event.

**UPDATE:**

```
$('.draggable').draggable({ 
  start: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#dropdownAddTile').slideDown();
    ui.draggable.find('a').click(function(e) { 
      e.preventDefault(); 
    });
  },  
  stop: function() {
    $('#dropdownAddTile').slideUp();
  }, 
  containment: '#container', 
  snap:'.droppable', 
  snapMode:'inner', 
  revert:'invalid',
  snapTolerance: 32
});
```

so you can call `ui.draggable.find('a').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();`

Comment: I tried adding that into the start function when declaring the draggable like: $('.draggable').draggable({ start: function() - note see above edit in my Qu for fuller code. But it didn't work. I'm a bit new to JS where's the correct place to put it?

Comment: I've edited the code you posted in your question to add  `event, ui` parameters then you need to later use `ui.blabla` , try that..

Comment: I'm sorry, total newbie here. ui.blabla not sure what you mean. Thanks for helping tho:) can you explain?

Comment: Thanks. I tried but I think because my .draggable class is actually set to a <a href class="draggable"> removing the link stops it actually being draggable. Nightmare. Is there any other way? I get what you were saying tho, v.clever man

Comment: If you could reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle and post the link here it would be easy for us to try things and help you..

Answer (score 0):

The issue didn't arise in Chrome, Firefox, or IE10 but it did happen in IE9 and lower.

My advice would be to run `preventDefault` on the event. Using your code,

```
function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var draggable = ui.draggable;
    var droppable = $(this);
    var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");
    var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
    $('.draggable').draggable({containment: '#container', snap:'.droppable', snapMode:'inner', revert:'invalid',snapTolerance: 32});
    $('.droppable').droppable({drop: handleDropEvent, accept: function(e){if(e.hasClass('draggable')) { if (!$(this).hasClass('occupied')) {return true; }}}});
    var initPosit = ui.draggable.parent().attr('id');

    $.post("tiles/updateTilePosition", { draggableId:draggableId, droppableId: droppableId }).done(function(data) {

    })
    $(this).addClass('occupied');
    ui.draggable.parent().removeClass('occupied');
    if($(ui.draggable).parent() !==$(this)){
        $(ui.draggable).appendTo($( this ));
    }
}
```

Also, if you view your source code, everything is encoded (apostrophes, quotes, etc.) Not sure how that happened but I'd fix that.

Comment: I tried that but it did't work. Not sure what you mean about encoded quotes etc...

Comment: @PatrickGuinness Here's a picture of what I'm talking about: http://i.imgur.com/3belgB8.png

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the onclick to 
    return false;

Answer (score -3):

If I understood correctly you just want the a link not to be drag able right?
Do this:

```
<a href="#test" draggable="false">Test</a>
```

This is basically how you disable the drag function idk why everyone writes such a long code for this....

Comment: you should also do this